# preserving data for timespan column while partitioning table into multiple disks

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I need to partition a table into multiple files over multiple disks. Below is the create table.

The challenge we are having is that, while partitioning this huge table, `ts` timestamp data will be lost (will be overwritten to new timestamp). How can i avoid that?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit](

       [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,

       [ObjectName] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,

       [IUD] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,

       [ts] [timestamp] NULL,

       [username] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,

       [IP] [varchar](50) NULL,

       [MAC] [varchar](50) NULL,

       [ChangeSet] [xml] NULL,

       [Key1] [varchar](50) NULL,

       [Key2] [varchar](50) NULL,

       [Date] [datetime] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Audith] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

       [Id] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't write to a timestamp.  By the way, rowversion is the new type, timestamp has been deprecated.  If you're on a version that supports the new type, you should probably do so.

If you really need to keep the old rowversion, you can keep it in a varbinary column.  However, you wouldn't know whether the row had been updated since conversion.  I suppose you could put a trigger on the table to NULL the old timestamp on updates after you convert.  Then you could have a computed column on ISNULL(OLD_TS, TS).  It's up to you whether the additional overhead and storage for the separate column(s) is worth it.

You could also store the new timestamp as of conversion in a separate table.  You can't put it in the same table, because an after update trigger would increment the timestamp and thus defeat the purpose of storing the original timestamp.  And the rowversion isn't available in the inserted pseudotable on an instead of trigger (at least in 2008 v2, I've tried it).  However, this means a join, and if you're partitioning I suspect that we're talking about a large dataset.  So I include this more to warn you against trying to store rowversion on conversion in the table via triggers.

Comment: in so many words i cant keep it. is that correct? thanks for detailed explanation by the way.

Comment: Not in the same column, no.